# Receiving error from mongoexport with date query

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am running mongoexport (v 4.2 on server and client machine) in Powershell on Windows 10 with the following command (network specifics removed)

`mongoexport -q='{"updatedAt":{"$gte":{"$date": "2019-12-24T09:36:56.312Z"}}}' --db=somedb --collection=orders --out=C:\OutputJson\OrdersDay.json`

and I receive the following error:

`query '[123 117 112 100 97 116 101 100 65 116 58 123 36 103 116 101 58 123 36 100 97 116 101 58 32 50 48 49 57 45 49 50 45 50 52 84 48 57 58 51 54 58 53 54 46 51 49 50 90 125 125 125]' is not valid JSON: invalid character '-' after object key:value pair`

I think it is referring to the dashes in the date, but this is how the docs say to format it. I have tried wrapping with double quotes around the query with single quotes inside and have also tried same with doubled double quotes inside. The same command works fine if we run with no -q or with -q=''.

An associate running MacOS is reporting that he can run this command just fine.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Please post a sample document from the `orders` collection (you are trying to export from).

Comment: @prasad_ I can do that, but how is that related? The error is saying that the query is invalid JSON.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with the query (I want to relate correctly with the data)?